# Exposed nails in new garage

Tags: nails

I'm having a garage built without drywall.  There are a lot of nails protruding from the inside of the OSB board.  i.e. Lots of missed nail-gun nails.  Is there any code or requirement for these nails sticking out beside very poor workmanship?  And what is the best way to cut them off without disturbing the sheathing or wrap?

Comment: Can you add a photo or two? What type of siding is on the garage?  I'm guessing these nails are holding the siding to the sheathing, not the sheathing to the studs.

Comment: They are the nails at the sheathing stage (sheathing to studs), not the siding(fortunately).  It really looks like someone that had no clue had the nail gun.  After the first or second miss, they should have had a hint that there was a problem.  This is all around on a 24' x 30' garage.  I'm trying to find if there is a code that may relate because the final inspection has not been done.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what type of code you expect to find? There are fastener schedules, that say how many fasteners are required, and at what spacing. Obviously fasteners are expected to be placed properly, otherwise they shouldn't count towards meeting the requirements. If you're not satisfied with the construction, you should complain to the company that did the work, and/or request a new inspection from the city/town.

Answer (score 2):

We call those "shiners" and it happens to the best of them (although having them "all over" is indeed a bad sign).

The best tool, because it can reach into stud/rafter bays, cuts nearly flush, and is the tool least likely to cause damage, is an **end nipper**:

[image]

Comment: I used to use those but when they get dull it takes more hand force than my 6'5" frame can handle.

Answer (score 1):

A small pair of bolt cutters 18-24" will do the job and last for years. I hate it when I miss it happens But I usually can feel it in the gun and adjust. After checking I usually snip the nails. If ring shank this is the best thing to do as pulling will tear up the siding. Code requires the nails to be in the studs but really says nothing about misses in my state. Look on the outside where there are a misses there should be a nail just to the side into the stud if not the siding may not be attached property.